# Give state diagrams of DFAs recognizing the following languages. In all parts the alphabet is {0,1 }

Tags: deterministic

Im trying to get the hang of drawing DFAs. I have the following problem to do with my following attempt, was wondering if anyone could tell me if im correct, or if incorrect what im doing wrong. Thanks! Also, if anyone has a good resource to learn more about how to do these, it would be greatly appreciated.

Give state diagrams of DFAs recognizing the following languages. In all parts the alphabet is {0,1 }

{w | the length of w is at most 5}

[image]

Comment: What happens if I choose the following sequence?  `000000`

Comment: I updated the problem, so it can proceed. Now if it has a length more than 5, it will stop. Would this be correct or am i still off?

Comment: Your DFA accepts 111101, which is not in the language, and rejects the empty string, 1, 11, 111, and 1111, all of which *are* in the language.

Comment: @jfisk What's the `g` before the { }? Is it the index of the question?

Comment: This belongs on cstheory.SE, but I don't know how to flag it as such.

Comment: @quasiverse I believe that's the sub-problem number (i.e., problem 13.g.).

Comment: @cheeken @ quasiverse it is a sub problem

Comment: On a 3rd look it looks like the first 5 states could be accept states, with a 6th transitioning back to the 6th state?

Comment: @jfisk Super close.  Remember that your DFA must accept the empty string as well.

Comment: @jfisk: If you update your DFA in response to answers & comments, it would be better to leave the original DFA in the question -- otherwise you lose the context of the previous answers, and diminish their usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some clues.

- "At most 5": this implies you must do some counting.  In state machines, counting is accomplished by the context of each node.  In other words, you will require a number of nodes, each with a special meaning, and that meaning will be your "counter value."
- "At most 5": This means you must accept words of length 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.  (All of which have unique values, hint hint.)
- Your alphabet is `{0,1}`, but there are no requirements of the language of the frequency, ordering, or anything related to `0` and `1`.  This means every time there is a transition for `0`, the same transition must be available to `1`, and vice versa.  (Or some equivalent relation that reduces to this rule - but this is in parentheses because it's not something you need to think about.)

Comment: Your latest DFA works for this language: `{w | the length of w is exactly 5}`.  How can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the DFA shown above is wrong.  It will accept strings up to length 5 so you should make all the first six states to be final states.  You are accepting only '1's but it should also accept '0's......so attach 0 with all 1's.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your errors:

- You have no marked start state.
- The strings "0", "" (the empty string), "1" are rejected, but are within the prescribed language.  In other words, you are accepting only words that are *exactly* length 5, not all words that are length 5 and less.

Since the alphabet is {0, 1}, you must specify at EACH state what happens when either a 0 or a 1 is encountered.  If you encounter an input character whose edge is NOT specified, by convention you are going to the dead state, a state that always returns to itself and is never accepted, but is left undrawn.  This is why your right-most state is unnecessary, but your left states are incomplete.

Final, big hint: You can have more than one "Accept" or "Final" state.

Comment: I will update the graphic to include the arrow to the start state

Comment: Are you seeing the same picture I am?  From the start state, there appears to be no edge labeled "0".  You should relabel the "1" as "0, 1".